# Get Array length from one class to another class

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

i need help in getting the array length from another class. i.e., passing the length of array from one class to another. Here is the problem.

**Testmatrix.java**

```
public class TestMatrix{
int rows;
int cols;
double data[][] = new double[4][4];

public TestMatrix() {
    super();

    rows=1; cols=1; 
    for(int i=0; i<=rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=cols;j++)
        {   
           data[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

public void print(){

for (int i = 0; i <data.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <data[0].length ; j++) {
             System.out.print(data[i][j]+" ");          
        } 
        System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Here is the main class
 **Main.java**

```
 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    TestMatrix m1 = new TestMatrix();
    m1.print();
   }
}
```

Everything seems right in the constructor. But the problem is the print function. The size of the data should be 2. But its is taking the value of 4 declared that is initialised. Someone solve this for me. I need to get to print 2x2 matrix( with all 0's) but i'm getting 4x4 matrix( with all 0's)

Thanks in advance **

Comment: Any reason to tag this `c++`?

Comment: i thought this question could reach people fast

Comment: tag spamming is frowned upon as it potentially draws the wrong demographic to look at your question which has irrelevant tags

Comment: The content of the array does not determine the length.

Comment: Yup, sorry EdChum

Comment: Murat K. Where.. in print functon?

Comment: In Matrix function, it is 2x2 matrix... problem is with the print function

Comment: Do it like any other matrix library out there and use a 1d "array"(std::vector).  Then you math to fake it being multidimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing array doesn't change the size of an array. If you want to print acording to new row and column size, change your `print()` method to:

```
public void print() {    
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols ; j++) {
             System.out.print(data[i][j]);          
        } 
        System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Again, constructor name should be same as class name. But the constructor of `TestMatrix` is `Matrix`.

**Note:**  Another important thing, you don't need to initialize the double array to 0.0. This array is by default initialized to 0.0 as this is an instance field of the class. According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created.
>
> For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.

---

Also, change your `TestMatrix(int rows, int cols, double[] data)` constructor to:

```
// declare with a large size
double data[][] = new double[80][80];

public TestMatrix(int rows, int cols, double[] data) {
    super();
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            this.data[i][j] = data[k++];
        }
    }
}
```

Better practice would be making the fields `private` and write getter and setter methods for those fields.

Comment: what if i have to pass the values of array from another class. It's the same scenario. what changes should i make in print function in order to print values of an array from another class

Comment: Don't understand. Are you talking about printing `data[][]` from `Testmatrix` class in `Main` class?

Comment: yes, something like that, in main if i have an array with elements. and then m1.print(); then i should get output a matrix with values other than zero's

Comment: so what changes should i make in print function in order to get the values of an array. Now, at present im not able to print values. Im getting zero's only when i executed function like this -

Comment: `double a[] = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4, 6.2, 8.2, 1.3, 4.2};`
`TestMatrix m3 = new testMatrix(4, 2, a);`

Comment: At first tell me how you are running TestMatrix class with different name `Matrix` constructor? Shouldn't be it `TestMatrix() `? And if you want `TestMatrix m3 = new testMatrix(4, 2, a)` then you need a constructor `testMatrix(int, int, double [])`. Do you have it??

Comment: yes u r right., It's TestMatrix. and yes i do have that constructor

Comment: That constructor also working fine. I tested it using println statements. it's working fine. But when i'm using to print with testmatrix(4,2,a). I'm getting 0's. Help me with this

Comment: Another question, you have a 2D array in TestMatrix class, but sending an 1D array. How do you want to do this?

Comment: `public TestMatrix(int rows, int cols, double[] data) {
  super();
  this.rows = rows;
  this.cols = cols;
  double data1[][] = new double[80][80];
  for (int i = 0, k=0; i < rows; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
             data1[i][j] = data[k++];
             System.out.print(data1[i][j]+" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
  }
 }`

Comment: This is how I did it @Shahid Those println statements are just for debugging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123545/discussion-between-shahid-and-chandra-kishore).

Comment: like this i can convert 1D to 2D

Answer (score 4):

When you create an array, you set the size, for example `new double[4][4]` then that's already the size of this array, even tho you didn't insert anything in there. My point is that no matter if you insert 1 element, 2 elements, or 8 elements, that doesn't matter, inserting to array doesn't change it's size (property returned by `length`). Imagine a bag, you have a bag with a certain size, doesn't matter if you put items in there, size of a bag is gonna stay the same.

Comment: Yep! Understood

Answer (score 2):

You declared your array as a 4x4 matrix. Line 4 should be `double data[][] = new double[2][2];` in order to achieve what you seem to want.

Comment: sir, but what if i want 3x3 matrix. That could be just a temporary solution. thanks bro anyway. comeup with another answer.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Comment: Jack bro!! where is your answer

Comment: @Chandra: You need to redeclare your array size anyway, if you do it like that and want to have it dynamic. Or use an ArrayList of ArrayLists to make resizing dynamic, but this might slow it down.

Comment: Find it below last one.

Comment: "below" or "above" don't work here, because the answers are sorted by ranking, which changes constantly. ;)

Comment: Hmm this might help.. But is there a way by sticking to this method instead

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean with this question. Do you want to get the matrix size of an instance of your `TestMatrix` class in your `main` method? Then add a getter for this and call it.

Comment: Or you can do one thing when you are getting rows and cols number at that time only initialize matrix like 2*2 or 3*3

Comment: Like after your statement rows=1; cols=1;

Answer (score 1):

Either declare matrix to 2*2 as said by Chris 
or change

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < data.length ; j++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rows ; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j <= cols ; j++) {
```

If you want any size of matrix upto 4*4 use second solution.

Comment: Perfect Jack!! That Worked!! Thanks for quick response. Thumsup

Comment: @ChandraKishore i prefer you should initialize Matrix at the time you get to know rows and cols

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this;

```
public class Matrix {
    public final double[][] values;
    public final int rows;
    public final int cols;

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        values = new double[rows][cols]; // Automatically 0.0.
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                System.out.printf(" %6f", values[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

Matrix m = new Matrix(2, 2);
...
```

`rows` and `cols` are redundant, as you already used `values.length`, and `values[0].length`.

Comment: Sir, what if i have to pass the values of array from another class. It's the same scenario. what changes should i make in print function in order to get values of an array from another class

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- Use an IDE, your code did not even compile, this is the minimum
  effort you should put into any problem.
- Declaring the array as double `data[][] = new double[4][4];` makes an array that is 4 "boxes" wide and 4 "boxes" tall. each box will hold a data of the type specified, in your case a double which you are setting to 0.0

  ```
  public class TestMatrix
  {
    int rows;

    int cols;

    double data[][] = new double[2][2];

    public TestMatrix()
    {

      rows = 1;
      cols = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
        {
          data[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
      }
    }

    public void print()
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++)
        {
          System.out.print(data[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      TestMatrix m1 = new TestMatrix();
      m1.print();
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to above answers

### i'm getting 4x4 matrix( with all 0's)

If you wanna find difference replace the existing lines with below code

```
data[i][j] = 1.0; 
System.out.print(data[i][j]+" ");
```

Hope you understand the reason for getting all the 0's

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be like this:

```
public class Test {

    int rows;
    int cols;
    double data[][] = new double[2][2];

    public void print() {

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" "+data[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test m1 = new Test();
        m1.print();
     }
}
```

and this part you can delete. You do not need it. This is not an initialization.

```
public void matrix() {

    rows = 1;
    cols = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++) {
            data[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```